# Javascript calculate function not calculating

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have recently been working on a project that has resulted in countless hours of frustration. The task is to create a Webpage that calculates a user's total cost depending on the different radio buttons / check boxes they select.

So, assuming all my other functions and constants are correct, is there anything wrong with my function or the calling of my function.

### HTML

```
   <input type = "button" value = "Submit" onclick="calculate();">

    <table>
      <tr><td>Workshop Total:</td>        <td><div id="divWorkshopTotal"></div></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Lodging Total:</td>         <td><div id="divLodgingTotal"></div></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Discount Amount:</td>       <td><div id="divDiscount"></div></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Sales Tax Amount:</td>      <td><div id="divSalesTaxAmount"></div></td></tr>  
      <tr><td>Total Due:</td>             <td><div id="divTotal"></div></td></tr>
    </table>
```

### JavaScript

```
 function $(elementName){
return document.getElementById(elementName);
}

function calculate(){

clearOutput();

if (checkWorkshopSelected() > 3){
    $("divWorkshopError").innerHTML = "* Selected workshops exceeds maximum of " + MAXIMUM_WORKSHOPS_SELECTED;
    return;
} else if (checkWorkshopSelected() == 0){
    $("divWorkshopError").innerHTML = "* No workshop(s) selected";
    return;
}

var workshopCost = calculateWorkshopTotalCost();
var lodgingCost =  calculateLodgingCost();
var subtotal =  workshopCost + lodgingCost;
var discountRate = calculateDiscountRate();
var discountAmount = subtotal * discountRate;

if ($("chkTaxExempt").checked == false){
    var salesTaxAmount = (subtotal - discountAmount) * SALES_TAX_RATE;
    }

var totalCost = subtotal - discountAmount + salesTaxAmount;

$("divWorkshopTotal").innerHTML = workshopCost;
$("divLodgingTotal").innerHTML = lodgingCost;
$("divDiscount").innerHTML = discountAmount;
$("divSalesTaxAmount").innerHTML = salesTaxAmount;
$("divTotal").innerHTML = totalCost;
}
```

Comment: `$(...)[0].innerHTML = ...` jQuery objects don't have the `innerHTML` property, `HTMLElement`s do. Use `[0]` to get the underlying `HTMLElement`.

Comment: try to use browser console and debugger to find the problem. press f12 to open developer tools in the browser and look what is written in the console

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the code and only ask small doubts in comments. Otherwise please make a new question.

```js
var SALES_TAX_RATE = 0.1,
    MAXIMUM_WORKSHOPS_SELECTED = 3;

var data = {
  productA: 10,
  productB: 20,
  productC: 25,
};

var prod = document.getElementsByClassName('prod'),
    tax = $("tax"),
    workshopTotal = $("workshopTotal"),
    lodgingTotal = $("lodgingTotal"),
    discount = $("discount"),
    salesTaxAmount = $("salesTaxAmount"),
    total = $("total"),
    workshopError = $("workshopError"),
    out = document.getElementsByClassName('out');

$("inputButton").addEventListener("click", calculate);
clearOutput();

function $(elementName){
  return document.getElementById(elementName);
}

function calculate () {

  clearOutput();

  if (checkWorkshopSelected() >= MAXIMUM_WORKSHOPS_SELECTED) {
    workshopError.innerHTML = "* Selected workshops exceeds maximum of " + MAXIMUM_WORKSHOPS_SELECTED;
    return;
  } else if (checkWorkshopSelected() == 0) {
    workshopError.innerHTML = "* No workshop(s) selected";
    return;
  }

  var workshopCost = calculateWorkshopTotalCost();
  var lodgingCost =  calculateLodgingCost();
  var subtotal =  workshopCost + lodgingCost;
  var discountRate = calculateDiscountRate();
  var discountAmount = subtotal * discountRate;
  var salesTax = 0;
  if (tax.checked == false){
    salesTax = (subtotal - discountAmount) * SALES_TAX_RATE;
  }

  var totalCost = subtotal - discountAmount + salesTax;

  outputPrice(workshopTotal, workshopCost);
  outputPrice(lodgingTotal, lodgingCost);
  outputPrice(discount, discountAmount);
  outputPrice(salesTaxAmount, salesTax);
  outputPrice(total, totalCost);
}

function clearOutput () {
  for (var i=0; i<out.length; i++) {
    var o = out[i];
    o.innerHTML = "0,00"
  }
  workshopError.innerHTML = "";
}

function checkWorkshopSelected () {
  var s = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<prod.length; i++) {
    var p = prod[i];
    if (p.checked) s += 1;
  }
  return s;
}

function calculateLodgingCost () {
  return 5;
}

function calculateWorkshopTotalCost () {
  var t = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<prod.length; i++) {
    var p = prod[i];
    if (p.checked) t += data[p.id];
  }
  return t;
}

function calculateDiscountRate () {
  return 0.05;
}

function outputPrice (e, p) {
  e.innerHTML = p.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 14px;
  width: 200px;
}
#inputButton {
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#workshopError {
  color: red;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.prod + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin: -6px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: monospace;
  float: right;
}
.out:before {
  content: "$";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="productA" class="prod"><label>Workshop A - 10</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="productB" class="prod"><label>Workshop B - 20</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="productC" class="prod"><label>Workshop C - 25</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="tax"><label>Tax 10%</label></p>
    <p><input id="inputButton" type="button" value="Submit"><label id="workshopError"></label></p>
    <p><label>Workshop Total:</label><span class="out" id="workshopTotal"></span></p>
    <p><label>Lodging Total:</label><span class="out" id="lodgingTotal"></span></p>
    <p><label>Discount Amount:</label><span class="out" id="discount"></span></p>
    <p><label>Sales Tax Amount:</label><span class="out" id="salesTaxAmount"></span></p>
    <p><label>Total Due:</label><span class="out" id="total"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```